# Training File/Folder missing in Google Colab directory

Tags: python

I was training an AI model on Google Colab and when its execuation is completed, it should save the model checkpoints in the colab directory (as previously) but, No files or folder there in the colab directory and the colab is disconneced. I have lost all the training files, how can i recover it or find it??

P.S: It happend two times in 2 days. Previously there is no issue like that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8rKM.png)

Training code/Command:

```
python finetune/finetune.py \
  --model_path="bigcode/starcoder"\
  --dataset_name="ArmelR/stack-exchange-instruction"\
  --subset="data/finetune"\
  --split="train"\
  --size_valid_set 10000\
  --streaming\
  --seq_length 2048\
  --max_steps 1000\
  --batch_size 1\
  --input_column_name="question"\
  --output_column_name="response"\ 
  --gradient_accumulation_steps 16\
  --learning_rate 1e-4\
  --lr_scheduler_type="cosine"\
  --num_warmup_steps 100\
  --weight_decay 0.05\
  --output_dir="./checkpoints" \
```

I want to recover my training files as there is some way to recover or not to lost it again?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read, write data and keeping it persistently is to mount data with Google Drive. Google Colab itself doesn't store the data persistently when the kernel is disconnected.

To mount the data to Google Drive using this snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then you can access your Google Drive content in `/content/drive` via the Files icon on the left panel.